# On click of an accordion should close other accordions

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, accordion, elementor

I use a custom accordion like this. When I click on the accordions other than the open accordion, the open one will be closed.

[Link is here](https://qarga.fun/elementor-9734/#neden)

Here are the css and jquery codes.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery(".toggle_trigger").on("click", function() {
    let $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('tab_active')) {
      $this.removeClass('tab_active');
      $this.next(".toggle_content").slideUp(200);
    } else {
      $this.toggleClass('tab_active');
      $this.next('.toggle_content').slideDown(200);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .toggle_content {
  display             : none
  }
.toggle_trigger {
  cursor              : pointer
  }
.arrow i {
  transition-duration : 0.5s;
  }
.tab_active .arrow i {
  transition-property : transform;
  -ms-transform       : rotate(180deg) !important;
  /* IE 9 */
  transform           : rotate(180deg) !important;
  transition-duration : 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried the codes I saw on a topic here on query, but I couldn't run it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: `I use a custom accordion like this.`  -> I use an answer like this too :/

Comment: sorry i had to do ctrl+k on every line while creating the code :S

Comment: HTML part is missing for [**a minimal and reproductible exemple**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as recomanded in SO guideline pages

Comment: I didn't write this with an html editor, I'm using wordpress and elementor. The link is above.

Comment: We can't help if we don't know your html, regardless where you wrote it in.

Comment: it is out of the question to copy all the code generated by wordpress but just the part related to this mechanism, and in a summarized way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
jQuery(".tab_active").removeClass('tab_active').next('.toggle_content').slideUp(200);
```

above `$this.toggleClass('tab_active');`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery(".toggle_trigger").on("click", function() {
    let $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('tab_active')) {
      $this.removeClass('tab_active');
      $this.next(".toggle_content").slideUp(200);
    } else {
      jQuery(".tab_active").removeClass('tab_active').next('.toggle_content').slideUp(200);
      $this.toggleClass('tab_active');
      $this.next('.toggle_content').slideDown(200);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .toggle_content {
  display             : none
  }
.toggle_trigger {
  cursor              : pointer
  }
.arrow i {
  transition-duration : 0.5s;
  }
.tab_active .arrow i {
  transition-property : transform;
  -ms-transform       : rotate(180deg) !important;
  /* IE 9 */
  transform           : rotate(180deg) !important;
  transition-duration : 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-76be618 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="76be618" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Neden Topraq</h2>        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-9e4407b elementor-widget elementor-widget-shortcode" data-id="9e4407b" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="shortcode.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-shortcode">       <div data-elementor-type="section" data-elementor-id="9953" class="elementor elementor-9953">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-2c162e6 elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="2c162e6" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-f5abe69" data-id="f5abe69" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated elementor-motion-effects-parent">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-97c365d elementor-section-content-middle toggle_trigger elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-motion-effects-element elementor-motion-effects-element-type-background" data-id="97c365d" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_motion_fx_scrolling&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_range&quot;:&quot;viewport&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_motion_fx_mouse&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_direction&quot;:&quot;negative&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:4,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]},&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_affectedRange&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;start&quot;:0,&quot;end&quot;:100}},&quot;background_motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;],&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:1,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]}}" style="--e-transform-transition-duration:100ms;"><div class="elementor-motion-effects-container"><div class="elementor-motion-effects-layer" style="width: 110%; height: 140%; --translateY:-11.0946px; --translateX:-0.0512785px; transform: translateY(var(--translateY))translateX(var(--translateX));"></div></div>
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c478d5a" data-id="c478d5a" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-dc04bcb elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="dc04bcb" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-seedling"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-40d4e0b" data-id="40d4e0b" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0484d07 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="0484d07" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <p class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Tarımın geleceğine inanıyoruz.</p>        </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-9017b78" data-id="9017b78" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2e8e59d arrow elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="2e8e59d" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-plus"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-d5e7c3e toggle_content elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="d5e7c3e" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c5bc8ad" data-id="c5bc8ad" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-183668f elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="183668f" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <p>Tarımı, veriyi ve matematiği seviyoruz. Büyük Veri, IoT ve Yapay Zeka’nın tarımın geleceği olacağına inanıyoruz.</p>                     </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-b663ac4 elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="b663ac4" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-ba5729d" data-id="ba5729d" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated elementor-motion-effects-parent">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-d382d7b elementor-section-content-middle toggle_trigger elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-motion-effects-element elementor-motion-effects-element-type-background" data-id="d382d7b" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_motion_fx_scrolling&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_range&quot;:&quot;viewport&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_motion_fx_mouse&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_direction&quot;:&quot;negative&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:4,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]},&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_affectedRange&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;start&quot;:0,&quot;end&quot;:100}},&quot;background_motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;],&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:1,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]}}" style="--e-transform-transition-duration:100ms;"><div class="elementor-motion-effects-container"><div class="elementor-motion-effects-layer" style="width: 110%; height: 140%; --translateY:-11.0946px; --translateX:-0.0512785px; transform: translateY(var(--translateY))translateX(var(--translateX));"></div></div>
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-cb136d4" data-id="cb136d4" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-62e888f elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="62e888f" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-coins"></i>         </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c9146cc" data-id="c9146cc" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4d9a61c elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="4d9a61c" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <p class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Abonelik modelimiz ile sizi yatırım yükünden kurtarıyoruz.</p>        </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-ce91189" data-id="ce91189" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d9a1a0e arrow elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="d9a1a0e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-plus"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-2323776 toggle_content elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="2323776" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-218e0eb" data-id="218e0eb" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c6fab98 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="c6fab98" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <p>Yolculuğumuz, tarımsal saha verilerine daha uygun maliyetler ile ulaşabilmek adına kendi donanımımızı tasarlamak ve üretmekle başladı. Makul fiyatlar ile tüm çiftçilerin Tarım Teknolojileri ürünlerine ve hizmet paketlerimize ulaşmasını hedefliyoruz.</p>                        </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-b3c9270 elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="b3c9270" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-98bd95f" data-id="98bd95f" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-2ca0b20 elementor-section-content-middle toggle_trigger elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="2ca0b20" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_range&quot;:&quot;viewport&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_direction&quot;:&quot;negative&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:4,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]},&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_affectedRange&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;start&quot;:0,&quot;end&quot;:100}},&quot;background_motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;],&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:1,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]}}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-2b7ffb3" data-id="2b7ffb3" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-5189048 elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="5189048" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-f9edd2b" data-id="f9edd2b" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2081d30 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="2081d30" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <p class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Karlılığınızı arttırın.</p>       </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-a3cebe6" data-id="a3cebe6" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2921e5c arrow elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="2921e5c" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-plus"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-1b718f2 toggle_content elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="1b718f2" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-f52e2f8" data-id="f52e2f8" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f8e3702 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="f8e3702" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <p>Su, gübre, enerji ve iş gücü gibi girdi maliyetlerindeki düşüş ile çiftçilerimizin karlılığının artmasını sağlıyor, sürdürülebilir tarım süreçlerini oluşturmalarına destek oluyoruz.</p>                        </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-dc7b054 elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="dc7b054" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-3138408" data-id="3138408" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-880f50c elementor-section-content-middle toggle_trigger elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="880f50c" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_range&quot;:&quot;viewport&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_effect&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_direction&quot;:&quot;negative&quot;,&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:4,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]},&quot;background_motion_fx_translateY_affectedRange&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sizes&quot;:{&quot;start&quot;:0,&quot;end&quot;:100}},&quot;background_motion_fx_devices&quot;:[&quot;desktop&quot;,&quot;tablet&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;],&quot;background_motion_fx_mouseTrack_speed&quot;:{&quot;unit&quot;:&quot;px&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:1,&quot;sizes&quot;:[]}}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c98078e" data-id="c98078e" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f1c10d0 elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="f1c10d0" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-cogs"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-bb00299" data-id="bb00299" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8725370 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="8725370" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <p class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">%100 Kurulum ve Teknik servis desteği ile sahadayız.</p>      </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-8c42bb6" data-id="8c42bb6" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-987304b arrow elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="987304b" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <div class="elementor-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-plus"></i>          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-3c2542f toggle_content elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="3c2542f" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-4cb3337" data-id="4cb3337" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-9ddac9d elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="9ddac9d" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <p>8 ülke, 40’dan fazla şehirde ekiplerimizle sahada direkt ürün &amp; servis kurulumu ve teknik destek sunuyoruz.</p>                      </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                        </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
```

P.S.
all this can be achieved in pure CSS without any bloatware jquery

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked and I understand what you mean. This was a ready-made piece of code, but I couldn't do it because I didn't know enough jquery to find a solution.